# Set last Fragment as starting point in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am developing a project in which I am using ViewPager on one screen. It has 7 pages.

For that I am using the following code:

```
tabsViewPager = (MyViewPager)findViewById(R.id.tabspager);
mTabsAdapter = new Tabsadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


//set adapter to tabs view
tabsViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

tabsViewPager.setEnabledSwipe(true);
tabsViewPager.setCurrentItem(6);
```

My adapter is:

```
public class Tabsadapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int TOTAL_TABS = 7;

    public Tabsadapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Index call", String.valueOf(index));
        Fragment fg=new ShowThoughtActivity();

         switch (index) {
            case 6:
                fg = new ShowThoughtActivity();
                break;
            case 5:
                fg = new Thought1Activity();
                break;
            case 4:
                fg = new Thought2Activity();
                break;
            case 3:
                fg = new Thought3Activity();
                break;
            case 2:
                fg = new Thought4Activity();
                break;
            case 1:
                fg = new Thought5Activity();
                break;
            case 0:
                fg = new Thought6Activity();
                break;
            }
         return fg;

    }

     @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return TOTAL_TABS;
    }

     @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
     @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
         if(object != null){
             return ((Fragment)object).getView() == view;
         }else{
             return false;
         }
     }

}
```

My problem is when I run this code ViewPager automatically scrolls to fragment 5, i.e. case 5 fragment.

I know FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem() creates two instances. But how can I set current last fragment as current?

Comment: try  tabsViewPager.setCurrentItem(7);

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet setting to 7 will thrown indexoutofboundexception